# Oracle: Connects with sqlplus but not from perl

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus, perl

I need to connect to an Oracle database from a perl script, it works in my tests and when using sqlplus, but not in production. This is a summary of the situation:

```
Oracle 11g XE (11.2.0.2.0) : (Test environment)
   sqlplus : OK
   perl    : OK

Oracle 11g    (11.2.0.4.0) : (Production environment)
   sqlplus : OK
   perl    : ERROR
```

The error reported is: `Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

I have triple checked the connection settings and are not mistaken.

#### Specifics:

- Test Server: Windows Server 2012
- Production Server: Windows Server (Unknown version)
- Client: Ubuntu 18.04 x64
- Perl: 5.26.1
- SQL*Plus: 12.2.0.1.0

#### SQL*Plus command:

```
sqlplus64 user/password@192.168.0.1/db_sid
```

#### Perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
$driver = "Oracle";
$sid    = "db_sid";
$host   = "192.168.0.1";
$dsn    = "DBI:$driver:sid=$sid;host=$host";
$dbh    = DBI->connect($dsn, "user", "password");
```

**Note**: I won't be able to test or execute anything in the production environment until next month.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The host is not found, perhaps a firewall issue.

Comment: How do you connect with sqlplus?  Usually you have to provide the port when you give SID and host. Typically you use the DB alias, see also https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#connect

Comment: Does the perl script requires another port open that I'm not aware? Btw, I was connected directly to the server (cross cable). I have updated the question including the sqlplus command (the server is using the default port). Thanks for the link. In 11.2, DRCP may be enabled, and it might be related to that or any other option that the server requires (and that sqlplus command is using by default).

Comment: Try `DBI:Oracle:192.168.0.1/db_sid` for $dsn

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : I will try that the next time and let you know if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: I tried `DBI:Oracle:192.168.0.1/db_sid` and it worked! Any reason why using `sid=` didn't work? (just curious). Can you please make your comment an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string format is wrong. Use

```
$dsn = "DBI:$driver:$host/$sid";
```